# Promise { <pending> }

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongodb, express

```
static async updatePaidLeave() {
    const result = await PaidUnpaidLeaveSchema.find({});
    console.log(result, ";;;;;;;");
  }

  static runCronJob() {
    cron.schedule("*/10 * * * * *", async () => {
      this.updatePaidLeave();
      console.log(this.updatePaidLeave(), "Im running in every 10 seconds.");
    });
  }
```

Output //  Promise {  } Im running in every 10 seconds.

i have tried above code and i want data from PaidUnpaidLeaveSchema

Comment: Did you try `await this.updatePaidLeave()` in `runCronJob` ?

Comment: are you aware that you are calling the function `updatePaidLeave` twice?

Comment: Yes i have tried "await this.updatePaidLeave()" but don't get any response

Comment: Because `updatePaidLeave` does not return any value.

Comment: static async updatePaidLeave() {
    const result = await PaidUnpaidLeaveSchema.find({});
    console.log(result);
    return result;
  } okay please anyone can tell me how I can get collection data in that function

Comment: how can i get data in that function ``````   static async updatePaidLeave() {
    const result = await PaidUnpaidLeaveSchema.find();
    console.log(result);
    return result;
  } `````````````` the data is present in PaidUnpaidLeaveSchema collection

Answer (score 0):

The code requires a couple of fixes. Try this (look at comments):

```
static async updatePaidLeave() {
   const result = await PaidUnpaidLeaveSchema.find({});
   console.log(result, ";;;;;;;");
   return result // return result
}
static runCronJob() {
    cron.schedule("*/10 * * * * *", async () => {
      const result = await this.updatePaidLeave(); // await and save result in a variable
      console.log(result, "Im running in every 10 seconds."); // log result
    });
  }
```

Comment: `updatePaidLeave` doesn't return anything…

Comment: how can i get data in that function ``````   static async updatePaidLeave() {
    const result = await PaidUnpaidLeaveSchema.find();
    console.log(result);
    return result;
  } `````````````` the data is present in PaidUnpaidLeaveSchema collection